# Simple search on a Globalize3 table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, globalize3

I am looking to implement a simple search function while using the globalize3 gem for Ruby on Rails.  Since the translations of the model are stored in a separate table, the code below doesn't work as there is no longer a :name field in the products table.  How can I adjust the code below to make the search function correctly?

**products_controller.rb**

```
 @products = Product.search(params[:search]).all
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>   
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>      
 <% end %>
```

**model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  attr_accessible :name, :price, :released_at

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're in luck, I tackled exactly the same problem recently!

Luckly for you the answer is quite simple. You can use the class method [`with_translations`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/blob/master/lib/globalize/active_record/class_methods.rb#L10) to include translations for a given set of locales.

Here's the code:

```
def with_translations(*locales)
  locales = translated_locales if locales.empty?
  includes(:translations).with_locales(locales).with_required_attributes
end
```

Include it in your `search` method:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    with_translations.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    with_translations
  end
end
```

That should do it.

As an added note: you could add an optional `locales` parameter to the search method and pass it to `with_translations` to optionally narrow the search to terms in a particular language, say for example in the current locale.

Comment: using 5.0.1 of gloablize I get 'with_required_attributes is deprecated and will be removed in the next release of Globalize.'

Comment: In postgresql it also required to specify table name before column name.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ...

```
    def index
        if params[:search]
          @at = []
          @at = Array.new
          Article.translation_class.where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%","%#{params[:search]}%").all.each do |t|
            @at.push t.article_id
          end
          @articles = Article.where(id: @at).recent_first.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
        else
          @articles = Article.all.recent_first.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
        end
      end
```